# brew utility on Linux: What's the difference from a something poured from a bottle vs built from source?

Tags: homebrew

Here is one brew "package":

```
brew info pyenv
pyenv: stable 1.2.18 (bottled), HEAD
Python version management
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv
/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.16 (671 files, 2.5MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2020-03-09 at 20:39:44
/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv/1.2.17 (696 files, 2.5MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2020-03-20 at 11:02:14
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/pyenv.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: autoconf ✔, openssl@1.1 ✘, pkg-config ✘, readline ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 48,345 (30 days), 179,715 (90 days), 619,315 (365 days)
install-on-request: 46,259 (30 days), 168,874 (90 days), 572,926 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

Here is a different brew "package" I have installed:

```
brew info pyenv-virtualenv
pyenv-virtualenv: stable 1.1.5, HEAD
Pyenv plugin to manage virtualenv
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv
/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv-virtualenv/1.1.5 (22 files, 65.4KB) *
  Built from source on 2020-03-20 at 11:12:52
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/pyenv-virtualenv.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: pyenv ✘
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
To enable auto-activation add to your profile:
  if which pyenv-virtualenv-init > /dev/null; then eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"; fi
==> Analytics
install: 9,469 (30 days), 32,494 (90 days), 104,366 (365 days)
install-on-request: 9,365 (30 days), 32,015 (90 days), 102,918 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

Why is one "poured from bottle" and the other one is "built from source". What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

A "bottle" is, in Homebrew’s jargon, a pre-compiled package. "Poured from bottle" means "installed using a pre-compiled package". `pyenv` has a bottle because it requires compilation while `pyenv-virtualenv` does not.

See the [docs](https://docs.brew.sh/Bottles).